# MQTT: publish multiple topics with mosquitto_pub from stdin

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have a simple program `gettemp` that prints out a single temperature every 3 seconds ...

```
$ gettemp -repeat 3
23.5 C
23.2 C
...
```

I can pipe that efficiently into the MQTT command line tool [`mosquitto_pub`](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_pub-1.html):

```
$ gettemp -repeat 3 | mosquitto_pub --stdin-line --topic /sensors/temp/outside
```

By *efficiently* i mean, there is no new `mosquitto_pub` process started every 3 seconds.

Now i have another program, that prints values from multiple sensors (radio thermometers), whenever new values are received:

```
$ temps_radio --format "temp_%n=%v C"
temp_0d=23.5 C
temp_02=11.3 C
temp_04=5.0 C
...
```

I would somehow like to pipe this data also into `mosquitto_pub`, but of course under seperate topics (like `/sensors/temp/0d`).

- I would *not* like to start a new `mosquitto_pub` for each new line!
- I dont know, how many differnt sensors `temps_radio` will spit out, so *i can not set up some named pipes*, let multiple `mosquitto_pub`'s read from them, and distribute the `temps_radio` output using some `awk` into these pipes.

Is it really neccessary to write an own program or script for that?

I was hoping that the use case "*feed a stream of key-value lines into MQTT*"  is a quite common.
On the other end for example, [`mosquitto_sub` supports user-formatted output](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html#outputformat), which makes it nice to pipe that out into another program, like

```
$ mosquitto_sub -t /sensors/temps/# -F "UPDATE Temperatures(%t, %p)" | mysqlcli
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you will have to write a program/script to do this.

Such a program is relatively trivial in something like python:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import sys
import re


def main():
  client = mqtt.Client()
  client.connect("localhost", 1883 , 60)
  client.loop_start()

  for line in sys.stdin:
    m = re.match('(.*)=(.*)', line)
    if m:
      client.publish(m.group(1), payload=m.group(2))

  time.sleep(2)
  client.loop_stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Run with:

```
temps_radio --format "temp_%n=%v C" | python publish.py
```

Comment: ... that was quick! Thank you! Looks you might have had a similar use case like mine ;-)

Answer (score 2):

one simple solution I can think of is using tail, since you don't want t o reinitiate mqtt, you can't do that with xargs.

I tested this in a linux env there maybe a workaround for windows as its tty behaviour is different.

so first, create a file that mosquitto will listen to like `touch temperature.pool`
then bind it to an opened mosquitto_pub

`tail temperature.pool | mosquitto_pub -l --topic /sensors/temp/outside`

this will not kill mosquitto_pub for every change in temperature.pool

then after that feed your executable output to temperature.pool
like:

`temps_radio --format "temp_%n=%v C" >> temperature.pool`

this will publish get temp output for every lines until its stopped.
from here you can add as many executable as you want to the pool file and it will be published

Comment: how does this publish to multiple different topics?

Comment: It will not publish to multiple topics, and naming variables inside each topic goes somewhoat against MQTT's idea of having separated (sub)topics for each data stream...